# how to create the popup notifications like whatsapp in android when in lock screen,home screen and using any other apps?

Tags: android, notifications, popup, whatsapp

how to create the popup notifications like whatsapp in android. It's possible for hybrid application?

Heads-up notification only shows the top of the screen.we need the full screen popup notification.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBCxk.jpg

It's shows in lock screen

Comment: [Custom Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We would love to help you, but there are some problems in the current format/content of your question that makes it hard for some of us to help. If you haven't done so already, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Alert dialog box can be good solution for this, which can be shown in certain condition.
Thank-you.

Comment: dialog box is possible for open in background of the app?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void oncreate(){
...
...
  myalertdialog();
}

public void myalertdialog(){
  sleep(6000);
  dialogbox();
}
public void dialogbox(){
  //your alert dialog here
}
```

Comment: I need the popup notification in app background https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBCxk.jpg